# Scanf() stores a newline when I type characters 'i' or 'n'

Tags: c

I'm trying to have my program end if the user types 'end' and while brainstorming for an implementation, one of the solutions I came up with has an interesting behavior.

In the code below, numbers are stored in ***firstArray.content[index];*** and letters/characters get stored in ***end[whileCounter]***. Everything works as intended, except when ***end*** gets an 'i' or an 'n'. When that happens, a new line character ***'\n'*** gets stored instead.

I searched online and in the debugger for an explanation of this interesting result but couldn't find a reason. Does anyone know why it happens?

Edit: It doesn't seem to be scanf()'s existing trailing issue as this only happens with specific characters.

Example: If I type ***4lol*** everything works as expected but if I type ***4null*** only **ull** gets stored in the character array.

I recreated this behavior in the code below:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct HeapArrRealNums {
    size_t size;
    size_t nextIndex;
    size_t currentIndex;
    double* content;
};

int main() {

    struct HeapArrRealNums firstArray = { 0 };
    firstArray.size = 4;
    firstArray.nextIndex = 1;
    firstArray.currentIndex = 0;
    firstArray.content = malloc(firstArray.size * sizeof(double));

    #define NOT_A_NUMBER  0
    int scanCheck;
    size_t index = firstArray.currentIndex;
    char end[6] = { 'c' };
    size_t whileCounter = 0;

    while ((scanCheck = scanf("%lf", &firstArray.content[index])) != 1) {
        if (scanCheck == EOF) {
            printf("\n----EOF. Program terminated----");
            firstArray.currentIndex = index;
            //return true;
        }
        if (scanCheck == NOT_A_NUMBER) {

            (void)scanf("%c", &end[whileCounter]);
            whileCounter++;
            printf("-%s-", end);
            //continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c"` -> `scanf(" %c"`. Otherwise `%c` will match the trailing `\n` from the previous number input. The extra space before `%c` tells it to skip spaces, including newline. See the duplicate post for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: @kaylum It doesn't unfortunately. I thought it would be a trailing issue at first but that wouldn't doesn't explain why only selected characters get affected by it.  If I were to type ***4lol*** the number **4** gets stored in the dynamic array and **lol** gets stored in the character array without any issues. But if I type ***4null***, **4** behaves correctly but only **ull** get stored in the character array. The character **'n' ** turns into the new line. Same with characters 'i' and 'e' exclusively.

Comment: @SarcasticLeo the characters do not get "turned into newlines" . The scanf will consume `n`, `i` and `e` because those are valid letters that can occur in a floating point representation .

Comment: As well as potentially eating good characters, the "eat bad characters" operation may cause a buffer overflow eventually  (and not clear why you are saving the bad character anyway).

Comment: @M.M Oh, I'm not. In my program, the implementation uses a `%*s` to ignore whitespaces and characters. That comment was left in by accident when copy-pasting

Comment: @M.M: I don't think `scanf` will consume `e` as the first character. It will consume it in the middle (or the `p` if the number starts with `0[xX]`), but numbers must start with a digit or a sign afaik. (I could be wrong and I'm not going to test it right now. :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is the first character in `inf` and `n` is the first character in `nan`. Those are legitimate inputs for the `%f` format conversion, so `scanf` will look at the next character. When it turns out the the next character is `\n`, `scanf` puts that character back into the input stream and returns a conversion failure.

But it doesn't put the `i`/`n` back, because the standard says that only one character can be returned to the input stream. The restriction comes from `ungetc`, which is documented as possibly failing if it is called more than once without a `getc` in between. `scanf` uses `ungetc` to return the character, at least in principle, and it's not allowed to try something which might fail.

Really, `scanf` is not a great interface for reading data more complicated than a sequence of numbers. But it can be made to work if you are aware of its limitations. When it's possible that either a number or a word is the next thing, try the word first:

```c
// This is one of a zillion variants on this theme. You need to be
// clear about your precise requirements.
unsigned char c;
int status;
while (1) {
  // Skip spaces but not newlines
  while ((status = scanf("%c", &c)) == 1
         && isspace(c) && c != '\n') { }
  if (status == EOF) break;
  if (c == '\n') {
    // Handle end of line
  }
  ungetc(c, stdin);
  if (isalpha(c)) {
    status = scanf("%5[a-zA-Z]", end);
    // do something with the word
  }
  else {
    status = scanf("%lf", &datum);
    if (status == 0) {
      // Handle conversion error
      // Note: the invalid character is back in the input.
    }
    // Handle datum
  } 
  // Continue looping
}
```

Comment: note - behaviour of `-` inside scanset is implementation-defined

Comment: @M.M: That's true, but it almost always works. I'll try to remember to leave a note.